# Android Kotlin Gradle multiple .kts files

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to migrate from Groovy to Kotlin. My project has several .gradle files, like `someFile.gradle`, `build.gradle`, etc.

What I used to do in my app-level `build.gradle`: `apply from: 'someFile.gradle'`

My `someFile.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.some.plugin'

somePlugin {
    param1 'string'
    param2 'string'
    param3 false
}
```

My `someFile.gradle.kts` after migration:

```
import com.some.plugin.SomePluginExtension

apply(plugin = "com.some.plugin")

configure<SomePluginExtension> {
    param1 = "string"
    param2 = "string"
    param3 = false
}
```

My  app-level `build.gradle.kts` after migration: `apply(from = "someFile.gradle.kts")`

When I try to sync the project with Gradle, I get this error on the line with import:

`e: /p/a/t/h/project/someFile.gradle.kts:1:12: Unresolved reference: some`

Other files, which have no imports work fine. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, still no luck :(

Comment: I would suggest check all your imports manually.  I had to go through the entire project after migrating to **AndroidX**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Here is my ticket on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34540

Comment: It looks to me that the plugin is  not added as a dependency.  The error message says unresolve reference: "some".  I think that "some" is the "some" in the plugin id "com.some.plugin".  That's what I think the plugin dependency is not added.  Roman doesn't show the build.gradle.kts script, so I can't be certain.